# Update base image in docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm new to docker. I'm trying to update an existing docker image .The image based on rabbitMQ but it has a lot of extra configuration. I need to update the version of the parent base(rabbitMq) so I have a few questions:
-Do I have to update rabbitMq from the terminal or DockerFile? Can I just change the version from the file?

```
FROM alpine:3.11 as downloader

RUN /*/

FROM rabbitmq:3.8.3-management as runtime
```

or just pull the latest version, stop the container and run it again?(https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-docker-image-container)

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is "hardcoded" to use `3.8.3-management`. You can either:

- Release and use a new version of your Dockerfile with an updated version

```
FROM alpine:3.11 as downloader

RUN /*/

FROM rabbitmq:3.9.11-management as runtime
```

- Always use the latest "management" version that gets retagged in the registry (although this is probably not ideal for production version control) - every time this is built it will use the latest version.

```
FROM alpine:3.11 as downloader

RUN /*/

FROM rabbitmq:management as runtime
```

Pulling the latest version won't make a difference since your Dockerfile is hardcoded and it's not rebuilt when the container runs anyway.

If you update the version tag in your Dockerfile, you can keep versioning inline with RabbitMQ, for example, with your current Dockerfile and then with your updated Dockerfile:

```
docker build . -t my-rabbit:v0.1-3.8.3
docker build . -t my-rabbit:v0.1-3.9.11
```